# Display a div onclick on a radio buttons in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've few radio buttons and checkboxes which controls a sub layer div.

Problem is when user activate an answer with a sub answer, and after the user selects another radio button, it hides the sub level opened few seconds ago.

How can I solve this issue please ?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Select the Answer 1.
2. Then the Answer A in the sub level.
3. Then sub level will be hidden whereas it should not.

---

```js
$('.form-group > label').find('> input:checkbox, > input:radio').on('change', function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('.row').hasClass('sub-question')) {
        el = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question');
        if (el.length > 0 && $(this).is(':checked')) { el.css('display', 'block'); }
        else {
            if ($(this).attr('type') == 'radio') {
                $(this).closest('.group-container').find('.sub-question').hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').css('display', 'none');
            }
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question :input[type="radio"], .sub-question :input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.sub-question {
    display: none;
    background: grey;
}
.tab:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 25% !important;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 bg-cover gray-light-bg">
    <div id="estimator" class="spacer pb-5 col-12 position-relative">
        <form id="estimator-form" action="">
            <div data-step="1" class="tab">
                <div class="group-container">
                    <h3>Question 1</h3>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
                        <label class="container_check">Answer 1
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="1">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="row sub-question">
                            <h3 class="col-12">Sub answers</h3>
                            <div class="row">    
                                <div class="form-group col-6">
                                    <label class="container_radio">Answer A
                                        <input type="radio" name="q3_1[]">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-6">
                                    <label class="container_radio">Answer B
                                        <input type="radio" name="q3_1[]">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
                        <label class="container_check">Answer 2
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="2">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="row sub-question">
                            <h3 class="col-12">Sub answers</h3>
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                    <label class="container_check">Answer A
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="1">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                    <label class="container_check">Answer B
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="2">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                    <label class="container_check">Answer C
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="3">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="container_check">Answer 3
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="3">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="container_check">Answer 4
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="4">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? or shall the sub answer close at some specific event?

I've chanced:

`$(this).closest('.group-container').find('.sub-question').hide();`

to:

`$(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').hide();`

```js
$('.form-group > label').find('> input:checkbox, > input:radio').on('change', function() {
  if (!$(this).closest('.row').hasClass('sub-question')) {
    el = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question');
    if (el.length > 0 && $(this).is(':checked')) {
      el.css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      if ($(this).attr('type') == 'radio') {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').hide();
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question').css('display', 'none');
      }
      $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.sub-question :input[type="radio"], .sub-question :input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-question {
  display: none;
  background: grey;
}

.tab:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 25% !important;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 bg-cover gray-light-bg">
  <div id="estimator" class="spacer pb-5 col-12 position-relative">
    <form id="estimator-form" action="">
      <div data-step="1" class="tab">
        <div class="group-container">
          <h3>Question 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
            <label class="container_check">Answer 1
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="1">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
            <div class="row sub-question">
              <h3 class="col-12">Sub answers</h3>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label class="container_radio">Answer A
                                        <input type="radio" name="q3_1[]">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                  <label class="container_radio">Answer B
                                        <input type="radio" name="q3_1[]">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-group-outer">
            <label class="container_check">Answer 2
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="2">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
            <div class="row sub-question">
              <h3 class="col-12">Sub answers</h3>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                  <label class="container_check">Answer A
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="1">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                  <label class="container_check">Answer B
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="2">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-4">
                  <label class="container_check">Answer C
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="q3_2[]" value="3">
                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="container_check">Answer 3
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="3">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="container_check">Answer 4
                            <input type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="4">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. First thanks for your help. I've changed my checkboxes to radio buttons, and after a click on the first option, a click on the second option will not close the first radio sub layer. Could you please help me with this? https://jsfiddle.net/ye2qu301/

Comment: Not really. The sub menu needs to remain open if one radio button (with sub-layer) is checked. If the user change its selection to another radio button, the previous sub layer should close.